# How to pull a single podcast source, using the Matrix field and loop?

Tags: matrix, forloop

```
{% if block.type == "podcastBlock" %}
    {% for category in block.podcastChannel %}
        {{category.title}} 

        <audio class="mp3" controls>

        {% for entry in block.podcastChannel %}
            <source src="{{ entry.audioFile.one.url }}" type="audio/mp3">
        {% endfor %} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}`
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you only want to pull in the `e2.mp3` file, is that right? Or you want to dynamically choose which one you show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was using two loops. I just needed the initial loop and referencing the loop call with the field-handle together. It now retrieves a single podcast.

```
{% if block.type == "podcastBlock" %}
    {% set groupTitle  = craft.categories.group('podcasts').one() %}

    {% for podcast in block.podcastChannel %} 
        <p class="subhead-section">{{ groupTitle }}</p>
        <audio class="mp3" controls>
        <source src="{{ podcast.audioFile.one.url }}" type="audio/mp3">
     {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Looping through queries is deprecated, that means sooner or later your `{% for podcast in block.podcastChannel %}` will trow an exception. Use `{% for podcast in block.podcastChannel.all() %}` instead. You can see this message in your control panel as well

Answer (score 1):

Try using the limit:1

```
{% for entry in block.podcastChannel.limit(1) %}
```